# Sencha build production error

Tags: sencha-touch-2, production

I had successfully create production build. When i am trying to access production build from chrome than i am getting below error

> Error: [Ext.Loader] Failed loading synchronously via XHR:
>   'src/field/Select.js'; please verify that the file exists. XHR status
>   code: 404

I had already included `Ext.field.Select` as requires in app.js.

Please tell me what should i do now

Answer (score 0):

Before the start of your script, i.e., in app.js. Try adding `Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled: true });` [Check this](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Loader)

or

Also, Set the src of sdk in app.js prod environment dir: [Ext.Loader](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Loader-cfg-paths)